# About renaming and merging tags and tags in general

Tags: discussion, tag, retagging

There are a lot of tags which I really don't understand or maybe would "re-name" or suggest to merge, one of those I would suggest to rename is:

- [comparative-madahib](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparative-madahib) i think a better name would be comparative-fiqh

**Some suggestions for merging**

[ill](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ill) (synonym [sick](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sick)) - [illness](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/illness)

Maybe a bit exaggerated:
[tajweed](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tajweed) - [quran-reciting](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quran-reciting) - [quran-reading](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quran-reading)

[ibadat](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ibadat) - [ibadah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ibadah)

[caliphate](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caliphate) - [khilafah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/khilafah) (already synonym [caliphet](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caliphet)) -[caliph](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caliph)  - [rashidi-caliphs](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rashidi-caliphs) maybe even successor should be added to that!

[kiblah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kiblah) - [qiblah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qiblah)

I would like to add the tag [najis](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/najis) to his synonyms like [taharah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taharah) even if they are opposites!

---

And I do ask myself if we need so much tags for about anything for example:

Accuracy, age, baby, blow, born, butcher, event, years ...
and a lot of things of daily use or daily life like ring, tv, movies ...

What do you think about that?

Comment: It looks like at least some of these have [been taken care of](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/a/1726/75).

Comment: @Caleb i know i just copied some tag names from here for the other post and made a minor edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My apologies for not responding to this one earlier; I was hoping that other members of the community would weigh in, and obviously nobody else bothered to. And then it fell off the front page and I sorta forgot about it…

I've subsequently synonymed [caliphate](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caliphate)→[khilafah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/khilafah) (see: https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1726/22), and it looks like [ill](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ill) and [kiblah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kiblah) no longer exist (either they were fixed before now, or they got caught in the automatic tag cleanup; either way, they're no longer an issue).

Unfortunately, there really is not a whole lot else that I can work with here, so far as the merge/rename requests are concerned. As a moderator, I'm more than happy to push synonyms and merges for things that are clear and obvious and exact synonyms whenever I see them. The problem is, for things that *aren't* clear and obvious and exact synonyms, I need to understand how the community is (a) *using* the tag, and (b) *wants* to use the tag.

Take, for example, [ibadah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ibadah) vs [ibadat](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ibadat). On the surface, this *seems* to me to be a simple case of variant transliteration. However, both tags have tag wiki entries:

- [ibadat](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ibadat)

  > Ibadat means slavery. In Islam, ibadah is the obedience, submission, and devotion to Allah (God) along with the ultimate love for Him.
- [ibadah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ibadah)

  > Ibadah means worship, examples for worship are: salat (five times prayer), zakat (Obligatory Charity), ziker (remembrance of Allah), and sawm (fasting).

These don't look like the same thing at all. Now, is this just sloppy tag wiki? Multiple interpretations of the same term? Two actually different terms? Are these tags actually *used* differently? Were they *intended* to be used differently?

As a moderator, I have no clue what to do with this.

In general, don't assume the community — not even the *moderators* — know everything. We're all volunteers here, and we all have various levels of knowledge. Even scholars may be experts in their own field but absolute beginners in others.

If you think that two terms should be merged, or a tag renamed, you need to make an actual argument for it. *Demonstrate* how the old way is actually flawed. *Explain* how your suggestion would actually improve things. Show concrete examples of how your suggestion makes the Internet a better place.

For the most part, if two tags aren't clear and obvious synonyms (even if they seem to be clear and obvious to you), they should probably be brought up in their own meta posts, where they can be explained in detail and argued and discussed by the community at large without confusing the issue with other unrelated tags.

In short, *argue* why you think your idea is better. Otherwise, your opinion is simply one voice among the thousands of other users who apparently don't have a problem with the status quo.

Comment: I think it would be good tn know who wrote the tag wikis for ibadah and ibadat the first sounds to me Arabic and the second like its Turkish (?) synonym with a clear misinterpretation in the first! Ibadah is worshiping and as Muslims we are called "Gods slaves" which my lead to the relation to slavery...

Comment: After reading both tag wikis extensively I reasoned that that they are clear synonyms, and I would say the Ibadat wiki is better but includes wrong information like slavery the author used parts of the referenced wikipedia definition in a wrong way! If possible please merge them and let me know I'll edit the wiki ASAP!