# New tags with strange transliteration

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms, transliteration

I often find tags which are not really useful because the authors just used a strange and non-common transliteration here are two "new" examples:
[isr-wal-miraj](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/isr-wal-miraj) for isra' and mi'raj
[jahanum](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jahanum) for jahanam, while [hell](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hell) already exists

It would be nice if they could changed re-tagged or whatever is necessary to make them useful for others!

So what is the usual way to deal with them?

And am i the only one who feel that we may have apparently for each possible transliteration a *tag-overflow* like [caliph](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caliph), [khilafah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/khilafah), [caliphate](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caliphate), [rashidi-caliphs](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rashidi-caliphs) or [kiblah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kiblah), [qiblah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qiblah) ...

Maybe as a result one should ask "**Can we find a consensus about how to transliterate?**"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With roughly 8k users (and roughly 10k visitors per day), you're bound to get the occasional sloppy tag.

When a bad tag is found, the best solution is to edit it into a *good* tag as soon as possible before it ends up getting used more: This is one reason the editing privilege is so fundamentally important to the Stack Exchange model (even anonymous users are allowed to *suggest* edits). Fixing one or two uses of a bad tag is a fairly trivial exercise for anyone (and I mean *anyone*) who cares to suggest an edit, but fixing a tag that's been applied to a hundred questions typically requires the direct intervention of a moderator (who then has the wonderful task of trying to sort out what to do with a *bad* tag that's also apparently a *useful* tag and a *popular* tag)

Whenever possible, I try to use Wikipedia's <strike>"Standard Transliteration"</strike> "[Basic Transcription](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aManual_of_Style/Arabic)" (and would recommend everyone else do the same, as argued [here](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9/22)). And tag-wise, I encourage having tags for English terms (as well as other common languages e.g. Urdu) synonymed to the transliterated Arabic, since not everyone who uses the site would necessarily know the proper Arabic terminology. So, for example, I've just applied the following:

- [caliphate](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caliphate) → [khilafah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/khilafah)
- [hell](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hell) → [jahannam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jahannam)

This way, even if a new question adds the tag [hell](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hell) or [caliphate](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caliphate), it'll apply [jahannam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jahannam) or [khilafah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/khilafah) instead.

Variant transliterations, ideally, would just be edited to match the "standard" one whenever they crop up. However, variants that are particularly common or that just keep cropping up can be added as new synonyms on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Thanks for the basic transcription link ... so my transliterations are "basically" correct ;). I understand the problem, but this is by far the SE community with the most tags and tag synonyms i know, that's why i asked!

Comment: @Medi1Saif I reckon Judaism.SE has much the same problem for much the same reason (http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transliteration), they're just better at keeping it under control because they're a graduated site with a much stronger community. Standard or no standard, it all comes down to how dedicated the userbase is to keeping things clean.

Comment: Then we should try hard to keep this community alive and make it better and stronger!