# Some micro-steps to improve tags (mid 2017)

Tags: discussion, tag

This is a continuation from [Some micro-steps to improve tags (early 2017)](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1848/17163).  Here's a list of steps to improve tag quality; I'm planning on doing these in increments so as to not flood the home page, and I'm posting it here to keep track.  Let me know if you disagree with these.

## Done:

These tags are gone: [salat-fajr](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salat-fajr)<sup>([meta thread](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2939/17163))</sup>, [will](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/will), [unbeliever](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unbeliever)<sup>([meta thread](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2985/17163))</sup>, [difference](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difference), [quran-ayat](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quran-ayat)<sup>([meta thread](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2939/17163))</sup>, [muslim](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muslim)<sup>([meta thread](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2940/17163))</sup>, [sunnah-hadith](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sunnah-hadith)<sup>([meta thread](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2939/17163))</sup>, [rasul](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rasul), [halal-consumer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-consumer)<sup>([meta thread](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1844/17163))</sup>, [islam-for-beginners](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islam-for-beginners)<sup>([meta thread](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3005/17163))</sup>, [sin-or-not](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin-or-not)<sup>([meta thread](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1844/17163))</sup>, [islamic-ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-ruling)<sup>([meta thread](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3075/17163))</sup>, [dead](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dead), [seafood](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seafood)

These tags are added/reviewed: [rajm](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rajm)

## To do:

**Tags to add:**

- [justice](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/justice) ([search](https://islam.stackexchange.com/search?q=justice+is%3Aquestion)).
- [lying](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lying) (search: [lying](https://islam.stackexchange.com/search?q=lying%20is%3Aquestion), [lie](https://islam.stackexchange.com/search?q=lie%20is%3Aquestion)).
- [behavior](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior) (search: [why do muslims](https://islam.stackexchange.com/search?q=why%20do%20muslims%20is%3Aquestion)).
- [blood](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blood) (search: [blood](https://islam.stackexchange.com/search?q=blood+is%3Aquestion)).
- [ashura](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ashura) (search: [ashura](https://islam.stackexchange.com/search?q=Ashura%20is%3Aquestion)).
- [pornography](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pornography) (search: [pornography](http://islam.stackexchange.com/search?q=pornography%20is:question)).
- [halal-certification](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-certification) (search: [certification](https://islam.stackexchange.com/search?q=certification%20is%3Aquestion)).
- [takbir](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/takbir) (search: [takbir](https://islam.stackexchange.com/search?q=takbir%20is%3Aquestion)).
- [perfume](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/perfume) (search: [perfume](https://islam.stackexchange.com/search?q=perfume%20is%3Aquestion)).
- [qisas](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qisas) (search: [qisas](http://qisas%20is:question)).
- Consider adding [earth](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/earth).
- Consider adding [abortion](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abortion).  See [What to do about the "birth-control", "family-planning" and "contraception" tags?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2972/17163).
- Consider adding [murder](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/murder).
- Consider adding [swearing](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swearing).

**Create meta threads about:**

- Closely related tags: [reciting](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reciting) (4), [reading-quran](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reading-quran) (22), [quran-recitation](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quran-recitation) (64), [tajweed](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tajweed) (13).
- Closely related tags: [work](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work) (56), [profession](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/profession) (12), and [business](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business) (53).
- Closely related tags: [verses](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verses) (9), and [ayah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ayah) (7)?
- Closely related tags: [drawing](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drawing) (16), [image](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image) (33), [depiction](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/depiction) (3), [photos](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photos) (10), [symbolism](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbolism) (8)?
- Closely related tags: [sajda](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sajda) (16), [prostration](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prostration) (7), [sujud](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sujud) (5)?
- Closely related tags: [terminology](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) (60), [definitions](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definitions) (28)?
- Closely related tags: [names](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/names) (26), [naming](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming) (46).

**Unresolved meta threads:**

- [Should "arabic-translation" be a synonym of "arabic"?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2986/17163)
- [What's the best way to reorganize the "kufr", "kuffar", "non-muslim" and "unbeliever" tags?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2985/17163)
- [What to do about the "birth-control", "family-planning" and "contraception" tags?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2972/17163)
- [Which questions should be tagged "sharia" and/or "fiqh"?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3141/17163)

Comment: seerah -> sirat Rasul Allah the biography of the prophet  I've written a tag info now.

Answer (score 1):

First your to do list sounds good and maybe we can expand it, at the moment I have no suggestions, but I hope we may add some later!

Secondly we have an issue of low activity here on meta as your unsolved posts show off, I'll try to take some time and hopefully be able to give my opinion on some of these open "Questions"... but no promise!

Third is it really necessary to open a new meta post for all your addressed threads (one of the reasons I ask this is "my second point" above)?

In some cases we may already answer or solve the issue here (especially when only two tags are involved)

Therefore I will comment more extensively on:

**Create meta threads about:**

- **Closely related tags:** [reciting](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reciting) **(after some editing:2)**, [reading-quran](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reading-quran) (22), [quran-recitation](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quran-recitation) **(after some editing:65)**, [tajweed](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tajweed) (13).

Well one can read the qur'an and recite it or do tajweed ("masterly" reciting based on rulings of tajweed)... the first two tags using the post- or perfix quran are not necessary equal to the last!
One may need to check in what context [reciting](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reciting) was used to include it in the others...
The first link I found is already not about qur'an recitation:
[Is it allowed to read something loudly in a mosque while some people are praying?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/38959/is-it-allowed-to-read-something-loudly-in-a-mosque-while-some-people-are-praying)

Reading (non-Muslims, people who read it in a different language than Arabic, people who can hardly read/recite in Arabic, while searching) and reciting qur'an (Arabic speakers, most Muslims) are also basically different so **my own opinion here is that all these 4 tags have a right to exist.**

---

- **Closely related tags:** [work](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work) (56), [profession](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/profession) (12), and [business](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business) (53).

they could be synonyms!-> **must be checked**

---

- **Closely related tags:** [verses](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verses) (9), and [ayah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ayah) (7)?

First thought: this is obvious-> they should be synonyms
Note that verses is plural and ayah is singular... is using the plural really a good idea? In this case I'd prefer a [verse](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verse) instead but of course one could counter in some cases more than a single verse might be in mentioned...

But we should take a second look at the use of [ayah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ayah), as ayah may mean evidence or sign in Arabic, but I'd use a tag [evidence](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evidence) for that.

As you see all those whom used this tag used it in the meaning of verse!

(Usage in post: [1](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33556/is-there-any-ayah-quran-ayat-which-has-been-revealed-by-dream) ayah = verse, [2](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/32729/is-receiving-money-as-interest-from-bank-deposits-haram) ayah = verse, [3](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/29642/how-should-i-interpret-quran-ab) ayah = verse, [4](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24389/is-it-a-sin-to-write-a-verse-or-hadith-incorrectly-and-does-this-imply-its-per) ayah = verse, [5](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16820/is-deleting-something-islamic-okay) ayah = verse, [6](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16371/which-surah-ends-with-the-name-of-two-prophets)  ayah = verse, [7](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12754/gelman-in-quran-is-gay-encouraged-in-heaven) ayah = verse , [8](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/10922/who-gave-ayatul-kursi-that-appellation%20obvious) ayah = verse, [9](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5702/which-quran-verses-mention-the-sahaba-companions)  ayah = verse and [10](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5566/how-many-ayaths-are-there-in-al-quran) ayah = verse)

**Therefore my suggestion** would be, due to the fact that both are included in a handful of posts, we may either:

- set them as **synonyms**,
- **create a tag verse** which includes both (my preference)
- or (**burninate**) include one in an other ayah has less posts and could easily be re-tagged verses.

---

- **Closely related tags:** [drawing](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drawing) (16), [image](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image) (33), [depiction](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/depiction) (3), [photos](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photos) (10), [symbolism](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbolism) (8)?

I'm not sure about symbolism the rest is rather related but I wouldn't say they are synonyms -> **must be checked**.

---

- **Closely related tags:** [sajda](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sajda) (16), [prostration](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prostration) (7), [sujud](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sujud) (5)?

yes... but maybe and **this could be discussed:**

- **English/Arabic what should we take?**
- **sajda singular vs. sujud Noun origin** the last is the one used in fiqh books
- and **is sujud including sujud at-tilawa** (while reciting the qur'an)

---

- **Closely related tags:** [terminology](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) (60), [definitions](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definitions) (28)?

sound like synonyms, must be checked!

---

- Closely related tags: [names](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/names) (26), [naming](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming) (46).

from my experience they are rather used as synonyms. And could be dealt with as such, so **I don't see a necessity to open a discussion.**

- [salat-qada](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salat-qada) (23) and [salat-al-qasr](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salat-al-qasr) (13) are inconsistent.

Not related at all: qasr is shortening a prayer, qada' or qaza' is praying a prayer later than its actual timing (or delaying the prayer and pray it later than it should).

---

- [seerah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seerah) (8) could mean [As-Sirāt][20] or [Sīrat Rasūl Allāh][21].

as-Sirat is different than seerah or sirat rasul Allah therfore I've edited the [seerah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seerah)!

---

At last I have a question:

When I started on ISE i was wondering about the multiple tags expressing the same thing at that time the solution suggested by GoldenPseudo, was declaring them synonyms, this of course helps catching new "tag" entries, as most of them would already exist.
See for example:
[About renaming and merging tags and tags in general](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1678/about-renaming-and-merging-tags-and-tags-in-general)
[New tags with strange transliteration](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1725/new-tags-with-strange-transliteration)

On the other hand having less tags makes things more clear and better arranged and easier to find, but it is time-consuming. This is what I assume is your ultimate goal, am I correct?

Comment: Thanks.  I still wouldn't be keen on doing these without a meta post first.  E.g.  In my English Qur'an, "ayah" is used to mean "evidence" rather than "verses".  And "business" is slightly different to "work", since it may refer to "a business".  (Salat-qada vs. salat-al-qasr seems to be my misunderstanding though.)